# How do I get the most recently updated form item to "stick" in Firefox when I copy its container?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I have a dl containing some input boxes that I "clone" with a bit of JavaScript like:

```
var newBox = document.createElement('dl'); 
var sourceBox = document.getElementById(oldkey); 
newBox.innerHTML = sourceBox.innerHTML; 
newBox.id = newkey;          
document.getElementById('boxes').appendChild(columnBox);
```

In IE, the form in sourceBox is duplicated in newBox, complete with user-supplied values.  In Firefox, last value entered in the orginal sourceBox is not present in newBox.  How do I make this "stick?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firefox vs. IE: innerHTML handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778/firefox-vs-ie-innerhtml-handling#36793) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `cloneNode` method. It might do a better job of copying the contents. It should also be faster in most cases

```
var newBox;
var sourceBox = document.getElementById(oldkey);
if (sourceBox.cloneNode) 
    newBox = sourceBox.cloneNode(true);
else {
    newBox = document.createElement(sourceBox.tagName); 
    newBox.innerHTML = sourceBox.innerHTML; 
}
newBox.id = newkey;              
document.getElementById('boxes').appendChild(newBox);
```

Comment: I got this to work by using prototype and changing  
  var sourceBox = document.getElementById(oldkey);  
to  
  var sourceBox = $(oldkey);

Comment: Does document.getElementById not work? I was under the impression that it was cross-browser

Answer (score 1):

Thanks folks.

I got things to work by using **[prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)** and changing `document.getElementById(oldkey)`
to `$(oldkey)`.

```
<script src="j/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

var newBox;  
var sourceBox = $(oldkey);  
if (sourceBox.cloneNode)  
     newBox = sourceBox.cloneNode(true);  
else {  
    newBox = document.createElement(sourceBox.tagName);  
    newBox.innerHTML = sourceBox.innerHTML;  
}  
newBox.id = newkey;  
document.getElementById('boxes').appendChild(newBox);
```