# document.getElementById('grand_total_display').innerHTML = "Total is : $"+variable; is displaying error in IE6 and IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

`document.getElementById('grand_total_display).innerHTML = "Total is : $"+variable;` is displaying error in IE6 and IE7

I have an `<li>`with id as **grand_total_display** with some text displayed in it.

```
<li class="bannerprice" id="grand_total_display">TOTAL PRICE : $0</li>
```

I am executing a jjavascript function to insert some other value into it.. but I am displayed with the error as given below:
[image]

Please help me to rectify the issue

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using a library (YUI, jQuery, etc.) to remove the cross-browser problems? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778/firefox-vs-ie-innerhtml-handling/36914#36914

Comment: @Matt Ball I tried with jQeury .html() to assign into innerhtml, but still display me same error

Comment: The code you posted has a syntax error. It's missing a closing single quote: `document.getElementById('grand_total_display').innerHTML = ...`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there's no element in the DOM with 'totaldisplay' as its id, or, as galambalazs suggests, you might have multiple elements with the same id.

With IE7 you can use ["Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar"](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) and ["Web Development Helper"](http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper) plugin, to find the problem.

Comment: The IE Dev Toolbar does not have a JavaScript debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong ID:

```
variable = "howdy";
document.getElementById('grand_total_display').innerHTML = "Total is : $"+variable;
```

instead of

```
variable = "howdy";
document.getElementById('totaldisplay').innerHTML = "Total is : $"+variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `<script>` is after the element `#totaldisplay` (also that the id is *unique* on your page).

Comment: There is no other element with same id