# Assigning value to <li> tag using its id displays me error in IE 6 and IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6, innerhtml

Assigning value to `<li>` tag using its id displays me error in IE 6 and IE7,,

Previously I was doing this:

```
document.getElementById("grandtotaldisplay").innerHTML = "TOTAL PRICE : $"+variable;
```

this throws me error in IE6 and IE7 as:
[image]

Then I tried with jQuery library as suggested my others.. then also I was prompted with same error as displayed above.

here is how I used the jQuery .html() 
$("#grandtotaldisplay").html("TOTAL PRICE : $"+variable);

I am facing this issue in IE6 and IE7

How should I resolve it..please help.

> **Update**
>   below is the `<li>` tag where i need to place the required value using javascript

```
<li class="bannerprice" id="grandtotaldisplay">TOTAL PRICE : $0</li>
```

Comment: Are you sure the element exists with this id (case sensitive) and that the id is unique?

Comment: yes it is unique and it exist

Comment: can you show us the HTML for which you are trying to use this javascript on ???

Comment: Are you calling the javascript after the element is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

you need to call that, only when the DOM is ready.

In other words, only when the page writes all tags, you can safely call them.

I would strongly recommend a frameworks to play with javascript, and writing plain javascript is now a pain and not fu at all :)

you can either call that javascript using the DOM Ready method, or append your javascript to the bottom of the page, instead the beginning.

```
<html>
  <head><title>my page</title></head>
  <body>
     <ul><li id="grandtotaldisplay">...</li></ul>

     <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#grandtotaldisplay").html("TOTAL PRICE : $"+variable);

     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

or append to any place but wrap it up with the DOM Ready method

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // safety call your DOM elements

    $("#grandtotaldisplay").html("TOTAL PRICE : $"+variable);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works: http://work.arounds.org/sandbox/41/run

This means that:

1. You are not doing the call on window load/DOM ready
2. You are dealing with iframes
3. You made a typo somewhere

Try putting your code inside of `window.onload = function(){  }` or put a script element before the end body tag.

EDIT: Based on your duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890659/document-getelementbyidgrand-total-display-innerhtml-total-is-variabl), if you're going to comment to my answer and say that it doesn't work, **PROVIDE THE FULL SOURCE CODE** or I'm not going to bother replying.

Comment: i have a ajax call on select box onchange which makes this <li> populated, so is there any thing I should do for everytime the ajax function has been called?

Comment: providing full source code would be very clumsy I am updating question with the structure how does it goes..

Comment: One more thing DO NOT GET ANGRY.. Please :)

Comment: Your initial `document.getElementById` will not work if the `<li>` is made dynamically. You will need to bind it **AFTER** the ajax request is complete. In the `success:function(){}` do the `$('#el').html()`. **The first time you call `getElementById` if the LI is not created, it can't be referenced.**

Comment: "providing full source code would be very clumsy I am updating question with the structure how does it goes" - you are wasting peoples time by not showing the actual code and context of the problem, which makes people guess. If you had provided a working replica, you would have got this solved the **first** time you posted the question.

Comment: @Meder I have a simple Ajax request without the use of jQuery.. Updated part has the Ajax functions I have used.. See above

Comment: I already edited my answer and provided a live demo of your new code which works.

Comment: Can you replace the PHP snippets with the output of the PHP? Or make it fake.

Comment: @meder I explained the output of the PHP code in the update pls seethe updated question

Comment: Why do you have                     `jQuery(document).ready( function() {` inside of another function? You shouldn't need that since the doc at that point should already be loaded.

Comment: Please specify which function doesn't work. You have **two** functions that have the innerHTML/html statements.

Comment: I was just testing it, pls tell me what should be done at that point as I am getting the error at that point only

Comment: Remove the document ready entirely. If you are creating the `li` dynamically, you need to reference it AFTER its been made, possibly in the same function.